Chrome dev tools show the JSON stringified data for AJAX paylaod as array in Next.js
I am sending this as payload of a fetch() call with this in the body of a Next.js project-
body: JSON.stringify({
  category_name: "Men's Fashion 255",
  _method: "PUT",
})

But when I view the payload in the devtools, it looks like this-
[{"category_id":3,"category_name":"Men's Fashion 255"}]

Why is it like an array?

probably you are sending that? where did the category_id come from

Actually I am sending this to the server over AJAX-
    `const updatedCategory = await updateCategory({
      category_id: 2,
      category_name: "Men's fashion 255",
    });`

But still the question is why the array in the payload. Maybe because I am not stringifiying it and sending direct object?
